# Start ios simulator without starting os

Tags: xcode, appium, ios-simulator

Everytime during tests simulator starts with process of loading OS. How I can start it instantly, with pre-loaded OS? Appium version - 1.4.13. Xcode version -7.3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) , it will be useful to raise your content quality

Answer (score 1):

SetCapability (fullReset,"false") this is answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot the device in order to run your tests on it.  It's not possible to run your tests on a device that is shutdown.  Thus, the device needs to boot first.

Comment: This answer still pertains to your edited question.  You need to boot the device.  It takes time to boot.  It is not possible to instantly boot.

Comment: SetCapability (fullReset,"false") this is answer